# NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<Object?>' has no instance getter 'keys'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

event.snapshot.value.keys couldn't read this code.
I using this same code on my other project.
And working great. Bu now not working.

I tried all kinds of different methods.
but it never worked.

Has anyone had such a problem?

This is my model;

```
class Country {
late String countryID;
late String countryName;
late bool enabled;

Country({
required this.countryID,
required this.countryName,
required this.enabled,
});

Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
countryID = json['country_id'] ?? "";
countryName = json['country_name'] ?? "";
enabled = json['enabled'] ?? false;
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
data['country_id'] = this.countryID;
data['country_name'] = this.countryName;
data['enabled'] = this.enabled;
return data;
}
}


--i got this error

E/flutter (21425): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] 
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<Object?>' has no 
instance getter 'keys'.
E/flutter (21425): Receiver: Instance(length:50) of '_GrowableList'
E/flutter (21425): Tried calling: keys
E/flutter (21425): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core- 
patch/object_patch.dart:63:5)
E/flutter (21425): #1      CountryController.subCountryStream.<anonymous 
closure>
package:srv_home_01/…/AuthControllers/country_controller.dart:54
E/flutter (21425): #2      _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:213:31)
```

Comment: it seems your `snapshot` deosn't have `keys` and what's `snapshot`?

Comment: same code working another application. but now didn't working

Comment: ok, so paste `snapshot` output into your post please

Comment: @DolDurma i shared

Comment: plase update your first post, don't post it as a new, here is not forum

Comment: guys i solved this problem. I spent 1 day for this problem.the problem is document names must be greater than 3 letters!